# Problema con los tipos de datos en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, conversión-de-tipos

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en forms de visual studio. Se trata de coger 3 datos: horas, minutos y segundos. El programa lo que va a hacer es añadir un segundo y decir que hora es. Cuando es el segundo 59, quiero que me ponga "00" y me sale "0" (lo mismo cuando cambia de 59 minutos). Intento forzar el tipo a string pero no sé como hacerlo.
Mando código:

```
        hora = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        minutos = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        segundos = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        sigSegundo = segundos + 1;

        if (sigSegundo == 60)
        {
            sigSegundo = 0;
            minutos = minutos + 1;
        }
        if (minutos == 60)
        {
            minutos = 00;
            hora = hora + 1;
        }
        if (hora >= 0 && hora < 24 && minutos >= 0 && minutos <= 60
           && segundos >= 0 && segundos <= 60)
                MessageBox.Show("La hora siguiente será: " + hora + ":" + minutos + ":" +
                    sigSegundo, "HORA SIGUIENTE");
         else
                MessageBox.Show("INTRODUZCA UN VALOR CORRECTO", "HORA SIGUIENTE");
```

Comment: Es un tema de formato de salida. Puedes hacer segundos.ToString("0#") para lograr la salida que esperas. Lo mismo con hora y minutos. Así cuando segundos vale 7 la salida será 07 y cuando sea 0 pues 00.

Answer (score 0):

No se cual es el fin del ejercicio pero creo que se debe al formato de string, intenta imprimir cada variable con el método ToString:

```
    hora.ToString("D2")
    minutos.ToString("D2")
    sigSegundo.ToString("D2")
```